# Display images as slideshow in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to display some images as a slide show in view (**MVC4**).

I am taking the physical path of those images in to one array[] in control.
and I want pass that array to view. there i want to display those images as a slide show.

**Controller:**

```
String[] ImagePath = { "D:\\Large\\1.jpg", "D:\\Large\\4.jpg", D:\\Large\\5.jpg", "D:\\Large\\6.jpg", "D:\\Large\\7.jpg" };
        return View(ImagePath);
```

**View:**

```
foreach(var item in Imagepath)
{
<img src=@ImagePath alt="Sample Image" width="300px" />
}
```

But it is not showing in view.

Is it possible to display images as slideshow using mvc4.

Comment: What do you mean by slideshow? If the images are showing up in the view then making them into a slideshow is JavaScript's job not part of ASP.NET MVC framework. Once your images are showing up in the view, then use one of many jquery slideshow plugins available and convert those raw images into a slide show. Another thing in your view code, you are using src=@ImagePath, it should be src=item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create this class first say in Model

```
public class ImageModel
{
List<string> _images = new List<string>();

    public ImageModel()
    {
        _images = new List<string>();
    }

    public List<string> Images
    {
        get { return _images; }
        set { _images = value; }
    }
}
```

then in the Controller use the following code

```
var imageFiles = new ProjectName.Models.ImageModel();
imageFiles.Images.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(imagepath));
return View(imageFiles);
```

in View you use it as

```
@model ImageModel
<div id="container">
<div class="photobanner">
    @for (int imgIndex = 0; imgIndex < Model.Images.Count; imgIndex++)
    {
        if (imgIndex == 0)
        {
          <img class="first" src = "@Model.Images[imgIndex]" alt="No Image" style="max-height: 110px; "/>  
        }
        else
        {
                <img src = "@Model.Images[imgIndex]" alt="No Image" style="max-height: 110px; "/> 
        }
    }
 </div>
```

you have to apply css as

```
/*photobanner*/

.photobanner {
height: 233px;
width: 3550px;
margin-bottom: 80px;
}

/*keyframe animations*/
.first {
-webkit-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
   -moz-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
     -o-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
        animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes "bannermove" {
 0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
    }
 100% {
    margin-left: -2125px;
   }
 }

 @-moz-keyframes bannermove {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -2125px;
  }
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes "bannermove" {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -2125px;
  }
 }

 @-ms-keyframes "bannermove" {
  0% {
  margin-left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
   margin-left: -2125px;
  }
 }

 @-o-keyframes "bannermove" {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -2125px;
  }
 }

.photobanner {
height: 233px;
width: 3550px;
margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.photobanner img {
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.photobanner img:hover {
-webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
-moz-transform: scale(1.1);
-o-transform: scale(1.1);
-ms-transform: scale(1.1);
transform: scale(1.1);
cursor: pointer;

-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

This code is a working code which i have tried from my side. Hope it may be helpful for you. In the image path specify the complete path say the physical path where the file resides

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(var item in Model.Imagepath) 
{ 
<img src=item alt="Sample Image" width="300px" /> 
}
```

...OR...

You should make the view use an `IEnumerable`, and then in the controller...

```
List<string> images = new List<string>();
images.Add("D:\\Large\\1.jpg");
images.Add("D:\\Large\\2.jpg");
etc...

return View(images);

foreach(var item in Model) 
    { 
    <img src=item alt="Sample Image" width="300px" /> 
    }
```

**note**: this is handwritten, so check syntax.

Comment: also make it clear to the OP that the "slideshow" part will have to be done using javascript