# Display Images as a slideshow for Mobile application using mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Display Images as a slideshow for Mobile application using mvc4.

i am taking the physical path of those images in to one array[] in control. and i want pass that array to view. there i want to display those images as a slide show.

here is my code

Controller code:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var imageFiles = new Mobile.Models.DisplayImages.ImageModel();
        imageFiles.Images.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"E:\05-11\New Folder\Images\BannerImages\"));
        for (int i = 0; i < imageFiles.Images.Count; i++)
        {
            // get rid of the fully qualified path name
            imageFiles.Images[i] = imageFiles.Images[i].Replace(@"E:\05-11\New Folder\Images\BannerImages\", "../../Images/BannerImages/");
            // change the slashes for web
            imageFiles.Images[i] = imageFiles.Images[i].Replace('\\', '/');
        }
        return View(imageFiles);
    }
```

Model Code:

```
public class DisplayImages
{
    public class ImageModel
    {
        List<string> _images = new List<string>();

        public ImageModel()
        {
            _images = new List<string>();
        }

        public List<string> Images
        {
            get { return _images; }
            set { _images = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

View Code:

```
 @for (int imgIndex = 0; imgIndex < Model.Images.Count; imgIndex++){
if (imgIndex == 0)
{
     <img class="first" src = "@Model.Images[imgIndex]" alt="No Image"/> 
}
else
{
     <img src = "@Model.Images[imgIndex]" alt="No Image"/> 
}
```

}

you can apply the styles in view file according to your requirement.

Comment: You need to use some javascript plugin. If you using jQuery, and by default there is jQuery in MVC4, you could use this slide show: http://wowslider.com/rq/jquery-slideshow/. You have examples of usage on their page.

Comment: it is a working model, edits made and fully functional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same question which was reposted by you. I have answered to it. You can find the solution in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20049631/2866502)

the solution is pasted here any how

create this class first say in Model

```
public class ImageModel
{
List<string> _images = new List<string>();

    public ImageModel()
    {
        _images = new List<string>();
    }

    public List<string> Images
    {
        get { return _images; }
        set { _images = value; }
    }
}
```

then in the Controller use the following code

```
var imageFiles = new ProjectName.Models.ImageModel();
imageFiles.Images.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(imagepath));
return View(imageFiles);
```

in View you use it as

```
@model ImageModel
@for (int imgIndex = 0; imgIndex < Model.Images.Count; imgIndex++)
{

if (imgIndex == 0)
{
     <img class="first" src = "@Model.Images[imgIndex]" alt="No Image" "/> 
}
else
{
     <img src = "@Model.Images[imgIndex]" alt="No Image "/> 
}
}
```

This code is a working code which i have tried from my side. Hope it may be helpful for you. In the image path specify the complete path say the physical path where the file resides

Comment: Thanks Saurabh. The earlier post was put on hold by some one for no reason. So i had to repost it again with new heading. Thanks for the answer.